# Dynamically nest CSS Classes in SASS

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I am trying to create dynamically nested classes in SASS. I am using React 18 and SASS 1.62 (Craco).

I have a scss file that needs to look like this

.gridRow.scss

```
.root {
  &.row-cols-auto>* {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
  }

  &.row-cols-1>* {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
  }

  &.row-cols-2>* {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
  }

  &.row-cols-3>* {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 33.3333333333%;
  }

  &.row-cols-4>* {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 25%;
  }

  &.row-cols-5>* {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 25%;
  }

  &.row-cols-6>* {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 16.6666666667%;
  }
}
```

I want to create dynamically all these CSS classes. For that, I wrote the following mixin:

```
$grid-row-columns: 6;

@mixin create-row-cols () {
  &.row-cols-auto>* {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
  }

  @for $i from 1 through $grid-row-columns {
    &.row-cols-#{$i}>* {
      flex: 0 0 auto;
      width: math.percentage(math.div(1, $i));
    }
  }
}
```

Yet, when I use the mixin as:

```
.root {
 @include create-row-cols()
}
```

It doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to fix it? I am out of ideas now. Thanks.

I tried to hard code the values, which worked.

I tried to inspect the bundled css file but couldn't find it, maybe peaking to it will show what it actually is created.

I tried to refactor the mixin function to look for typos, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason it didn't work is because your SASS version is a little low. Try to upgrade may resolve the issue.

Or another solution:
use `width: math.percentage(1/$i);` instead of `width: math.percentage(math.div(1, $i));`.

Below is my test:

[image]

My sass version is:

[image]

The dart-sass is:

[image]

And it works.

So I still believe your sass version is not high enough.

Comment: Actually Sass is updated to the latest version, and using division without math.div raises a warning in the linter

Comment: @JonatanKruszewski I've add some screenshots of my test env. You can check on your side.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Now that I see that in yours is working fine, I will check some other elements in the environment. I might have missed something else.

Comment: Thanks Jason, as you said, it was effectively working fine. The problem was in the className handling. It wasn't the version.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the problem wasn't in the SCSS but the react file.
It wasn't hitting the nail due to improper handling with classNames.

An example of a fixed component:

```
const Row = React.forwardRef(({
  as: Component,
  className,
  rowCols,
  g,
  gx,
  gy, 
  children,
  ...props
}, ref) => {

    // parse possible {XS: 4, ...} to {GridRow-row-cols-xs-4: 4, ...}
  const mappedRowCols = _.isObject(rowCols) ?
    _.mapKeys(rowCols, (value, key) => [styles[`row-cols-${_.toLower(key)}-${value}`]]) :
    rowCols && {[styles[`row-cols-${rowCols}`]]: rowCols};

  const mappedGutters = _.isObject(g) ?
    _.mapKeys(g, (value, key) => [styles[`g-${_.toLower(key)}-${value}`]]) :
    g && {[styles[`g-${g}`]]: g};

  const mappedGuttersX = _.mapKeys(gx, (value, key) => [styles[`gx-${_.toLower(key)}-${value}`]]);
  const mappedGuttersY = _.mapKeys(gy, (value, key) => [styles[`gy-${_.toLower(key)}-${value}`]]);

  return (
    <Component
      ref={ref}
      {...props}
      className={classNames(
        styles.root,
        mappedGuttersX,
        mappedGuttersY,
        mappedGutters,
        mappedRowCols,
        className)}
    >
      {children}
    </Component>
  );
});
```